# how to fix ClassCastException while querying registered temp table with udf in zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

```
data.registerTempTable('tweets')

sqlContext.registerJavaFunction("clean","a.b.c.Cleaner")

sqlContext.sql("SELECT clean(tweet) from tweets").show()
```

The above code runs on jupyter successfully but not in zeppelin.
I have loaded "a.b.c.Cleaner" jar with z.load(..), also tweets table is being registered successfully, it is visible on sql context.

Here is the stacktrace from zeppelin:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1693.showString.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 27.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 27.0 (TID 306, ip-172-31-14-210.eu-central-1.compute.internal, executor 10): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2292)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Driver stacktrace:
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2039)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2027)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2026)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2026)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
>       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:966)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2260)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2209)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2198)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3384)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2545)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2759)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:255)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor329.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>       at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>       at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>       at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2292)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       ... 1 more

()

Ps: same spark (2.4.0) is installed on both